# How to match an optional string at the beginning?

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm looking for a regular expression that will simplify what I have no without using an OR regex - `|` because I only want one capturing group.

The rules are to match anything at the beginning of the line that is a `x` with a space after it and then a single capital letter in ().

Or to match anything that is a capital letter in () at the start of the line.

```
^\(([A-Z])\)|^x \(([A-Z])\) # works with |
```

### Should Match

```
x (A) should match A
(B) should match B
```

### Should Not Match

```
should not match (Z)
x should (A) not match
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the `|` operator? What makes you think that, given that you specification itself contains the word "or", that you could implement a solution that does not in some way include an "or" operation? You ought to be a lot more specific about what the reasoning behind your question is, as at the moment it is not very clear what you're really trying to accomplish (seems a lot like an [XY Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377))

Comment: parsing the result is easier when there is only one capture group.

Comment: `^(?:x )?\([A-Z]\)`? See it here: https://regex101.com/r/r2HQ6D/1. You can obviously put `[A-Z]` in a capturing group if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply place the `x` and the space character in a non-capturing group and make it optional by using the [`?` quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html):

```
^(?:x )?\(([A-Z])\)
```

**[Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/PWprpP/1)**.

Alternatively, you can still use the `|` operator but have only one capturing group if you use a positive [Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=^x |^)\(([A-Z])\)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PWprpP/2)**.

You can even take it a step further and get rid of the capturing group completely and just have the capital letter as the entire match if you wish:

```
(?<=^x \(|^\()[A-Z](?=\))
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PWprpP/3)**.

That would be an overkill though. I'd go with the first solution.